# redux initialState - get total from other attributes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

i'm just starting out with react-redux and i've encountered a problem that was not an issue with plain react and state in components.

I have a reducer with initialState like this:

[image: code]

so yea i know i'm only declaring state and it has no idea about other attributes (or something along those lines :P ).

Action handlers are working, state changes, but i cant seem to get `total:` to give me sort of equation.

Anyone could point me into the right direction? how to make something like this work? is it even possible from initialState?

Comment: What do you imagine `upgradeOne` is? They don’t exist except as keys in an object—you’re treating them like they’re variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put something in state that you can compute from another value. This has nothing to do with redux. Compute the total in the render function. Or move into separate function like

```
totalClickPower() {
  const {upgradeOne, upgradeTwo} = this.props.clickPower
  return 1 + upgradeOne + upgradeTwo
}

render() {
  return <div>{this.totalClickPower()}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be that react and redux have no relation to this. 
It's just JS: probably, your `total` property gets its initial value `( 1 + undefined + undefined )`